# Run function when Socket.io emit completes

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for file uploading, and for an uploading animation I need to know when the emit event starts and ends. Is there an event in Socket.io for when an emit event finishes?

Comment: I agree with the answer below in principle. You could create a custom event but that isn't great. BUT if you don't have any control over the backend that still might be the answer you have to go with. If you have to do that, I'd also send a suggestion to whoever owns that backend to implement that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"for an uploading animation I need to know when the emit event starts and ends" - no, you don't. The 'emit' event is over once you've called it. What you need is for the back end to send you back some response that you can then intercept. So if your event was called `save`, the backend might send back a `save.complete` event. You need to find out what that event is, if it exists. If it doesn't, it needs to be implemented.